# No Such Column Error In Android SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I created database. But it gives me "no such column error". I'm sure that my database have that coloumn because i used SQLite Manager to add data. I don't understand why i am getting such error. I've searched this question here, but the answers never helped me.

Most of answers says that If there is no space between column name while writing this code, it gives this error. But i think i writed correctly.

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(
            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
           + BNUM_COL + " TEXT, " 
          + PNAME_COL + " TEXT, " 
          + AUTHOR_COL + " TEXT, " 
           + TYPE_COL + " TEXT, " 
           + PYEAR_COL + "INTEGER );");
  }
```

My Logcat also showed me :

```
Cursor c = db.query("btable", SELECT, null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The last field has no space between the column name and the keyword `INTEGER`. You need to change this line:

```
+ PYEAR_COL + "INTEGER );");
```

to this:

```
+ PYEAR_COL + " INTEGER );");
               ^
               |
               Note the extra space!
```

A simple diagnostic tool to help track down these kinds of errors is to store the SQL query in a variable and log it before trying to execute it. Then you can examine the logcat output to see what statement was actually built.

Comment: I can't still believe that i made this stupid mistake. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Adaichi - It may feel like a stupid mistake, but every programmer has made the same one (probably many times over). In my eyes, every line of my own code is always perfect (unless there's a `// FIXME` lurking around) until someone reviewing it for me says "Um, is this right?". (The answer is always, "[d'oh!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D'oh!)")

Comment: Good suggestion on storing and outputting the query